# Getting array of values from array of objects containing a certain key-value pair

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have an Array of Objects
`chars: [{'name':'tom','age':2},{'name':'jerry','age':3}]`

What's the aggregation to get
`chars: ['tom','jerry']` or `chars: 'tom,jerry'` ?

I know I can get
`chars: [{'name':'tom'},{'name':'jerry'}]` by `$project` on `chars.name`, but I want a more compact way to see what I have in the values since the keys are uninteresting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` with `$concatArrays` for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      chars: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$chars",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [
                "$$this.name"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJuPRmZEV5n)

The `$reduce` is iterating array elements and create one result from them.